# MKAnnotationView Customize callout - handle touch on a button

Tags: objective-c, mkannotationview, mapkit

I'm using the J4n0 Callout code ([github](https://github.com/j4n0/callout)), to implement a custom annotation in MapKit.

In my annotation (`MyCalloutView`) I'm using a button and a label.

When I'm clicking on my button, the methode handleTouch is called, but the sender correspond an `UITapGestureRecognizer` with `sender.view` always equal to my annotation view, and not the button.

**MyCalloutView.h**

```
@interface MyCalloutView : CalloutView

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* title;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *clickButton;

- (IBAction) handleTouch:(id)sender;

- (id) initWithAnnotation:(CalloutAnnotation*)annotation;

- (IBAction)onClickButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

**MyCalloutView.m**

```
@implementation MyCalloutView

-(IBAction) handleTouch:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    //LogDebug(@"touch from : %@", sender);
    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender.view;
    LogDebug(@"Sender class : %@ - Sender Tag : %d - Sender View class : %@", [sender class], sender.view.tag, sender.view.class);
    LogDebug(@"Tap postion : (%f, %f)", [sender locationInView:sender.view].x, [sender locationInView:sender.view].y);
    if(senderButton == self.clickButton){
        LogDebug(@"le clique vient de click button !!");
    }
}
[...]
```

**CalloutView.h**
    @class CalloutAnnotation;

```
@interface CalloutView : BaseCalloutView 

- (IBAction) handleTouch:(id)sender;
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(CalloutAnnotation*)annotation;

@end
```

**CalloutView.m**
    @implementation CalloutView

```
-(IBAction) handleTouch:(id)sender {
    LogDebug(@"touch %@", sender);
}


- (id)initWithAnnotation:(CalloutAnnotation*)annotation
{
    NSString *identifier = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    if (self!=nil){
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:identifier owner:self options:nil];
    }

    // prevent the tap and double tap from reaching views underneath

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouch:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubletapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouch:)];
    doubletapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:doubletapGestureRecognizer];


return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was a well known one. The solution is described in the GitHub : [issue 1](https://github.com/j4n0/callout/issues/1)

The solution works for me.